# Chmod 4750 on mounted filesystem with chroot (but chmod 750 works)

Tags: mount, gentoo, chroot, chmod

I was following the [gentoo installation guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base). But I stucked at the *updating the world set* part because I was not able to install dbus with emerge. It was failing to change SUID permission of its binary with a following log output:

```
chmod 4750 /var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/dbus-1.10.18/image//usr/libexec/dbus-daemon-launch-helper;
...
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/tmp/portage/sys-apps/dbus-1.10.18/image//usr/libexec/dbus-daemon-launch-helper': Permission denied
```

**So for example:**

I mount the filesystem as the root user:

```
mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/gentoo
```

After that I chroot to it (as the root user too):

```
chroot /mnt/gentoo /bin/bash
source /etc/profile
```

And creating a file and trying to change it's permissions

```
touch /hello
chmood 4750 /hello
```

fails saying "permission denied".

However `chmod 4750 /mnt/gentoo/hello` from the outside filesystem works fine.

Why permission is denied? I also tried mounting with `-o suid` but it doesn't seem to work either.

So how to make `chmod 4750` work on different fs?

**UPDATE:**
When I do the same thing from my linux mint it works. From the gentoo livecd it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gentoo livecd you used may be booting a hardened kernel. If so, you ran into the restrictions a hardened kernel imposes that cut short accessing and modifying stuff from within `chroot` environments. Setuid, GRUB and EFI come to mind. 
The first number 4 in the four digit notation `chmod 4750` refers to setting the setuid bit. The error message reports the attempt being denied, since it has security implications. In three digit notation `chmod 750` setting these permissions works, because no setuid is involved.

This answer owes to toralf, Hu and gengreen over at the a closely related discussion [over at the gentoo forums](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8191966.html).

So what you may find helpful following these steps:

1. Check if the current running kernel is "hardenend", usually `uname -r` gives back a string of `4.8.17-hardened-r2` or somesuch.

   ```
   # uname -r
   4.8.17-hardened-r2
   ```
2. Check if your kernel config allows for sysctl local configs, do `# zgrep GRKERNSEC_SYSCTL /proc/config.gz` - a result like this is fine:

   ```
   CONFIG_GRKERNSEC_SYSCTL=y
   CONFIG_GRKERNSEC_SYSCTL_ON=y
   ```
3. Be sure to do this and the next step outside the actual chrooted environment. Add a few lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf` - given that you're likely inside a temporary chroot environment anyway this seems ok, if not add these to `/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf`:

   ```
   kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_chmod = 0 
   kernel.grsecurity.chroot_caps = 0 
   kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_mount = 0
   ```
4. Last step, you run `# sysctl -p` to work those changes; it will repeat whatever rule is set in the config from step 3:

   ```
   # sysctl -p
   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
   kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_chmod = 0
   kernel.grsecurity.chroot_caps = 0
   kernel.grsecurity.chroot_deny_mount = 0
   ```

Then, jump into the chroot environment again (via `screen -x` if you're like me) and find that `emerge` needing to change permissions using SUID works as it should.

(On a side note, Gentoo stopped shipping these for reasons of restricted patch availability, see [article on LWN.net](https://lwn.net/Articles/731477/8191966.html). So those nice GUI equipped live environments need to be used carefully, and have never been a one size fits all.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the `mount` is adopting the non-writable status of the host environment (the livecd). Explicitly specify a read/write `mount` with the following:

`mount -o rw /dev/sdb3 /mnt/gentoo`

Be sure to `umount` it first.

Comment: I actually can read-write and set suid in the livecd filesystem. I can read-write to the filesystem on /dev/sdb3 from inside as well as to change file permissions except four digit ones. So I can set 750 but not 4750.

Comment: Oh I see! That is a bit odd. Sorry, I'm not much help then! Suggest adding that `chmod 750` works to the question might help clarify.